# Don't want appendix to show as a section in the navigation in Beamer (knit with R Markdown) Berlin theme

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, beamer

I have an appendix section in my Beamer presentation that I'm creating with R markdown, using the Berlin theme. Currently, this section is showing in the navigation bar, but I would like it not to. I've been able to suppress the Appendix from printing in the toc by specifying `{-}`, but this had no effect on the navigation bar. I've also tried including `\apppendix` as well as the package `appendixnumberbeamer` but neither worked. Any suggestions? (Reproducible example below- in my presentation, the code chunks are calls to `knitr::include_graphics(mylocalfilepath)`)

````
---
author: 
- Me
output:   
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "Berlin"
    colortheme: "beaver"
    fonttheme: "structurebold"
    toc: true
    slide_level: 2
---

# Introduction 

# Section One
# Slide Two
- Words

# Appendix {-}
## Slide One
```{r}
4+4
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing `# Appendix {-}`, insert the appropriate LaTeX command directly:

````
---
author: 
- Me
output:   
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "Berlin"
    colortheme: "beaver"
    fonttheme: "structurebold"
    toc: true
    slide_level: 2
---

# Introduction 

# Section One
## Slide Two
- Words

``` {=latex}
\end{frame}
\appendix
\begin{frame}<0| handout:0>
```

## Slide One
```{r}
4+4
```
````

This will close the final frame, mark the start of the appendix, and then insert an empty frame which will never be shown. This is hacky, but works.

Comment: I replaced the `# Appendix {-}` above with this snippet, but it returned an error "! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.347 \end{frame}"

Comment: That's caused by the preceding first level header, which doesn't create a slide. Using `## Solide two` should work.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to have made a difference- I get the same error as previously?

Comment: That's very weird. Sry, no idea what's wrong there (it works for me).

Comment: @sabrina I've updated the answer to include the full example. Does that snippet still give you the same error? Which R Markdown/pandoc version are you using?